# google api - how to get all the addresses for a chosen city/town/village

Tags: javascript, api, google-places-api

i'm using the google place api. My question is  how to get all the addresses for a chosen city/town/village. At this point thats my code:

```js
      var placeSearch, autocomplete;

      function initAutocomplete() {

        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});
      }

      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
```

```html
      Enter your city: <input style="width:480px" id="city" placeholder="Enter your city" type="text"></input></br>
      Enter your address: <input style="width:480px" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>

      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

So the "enter your address" input works. But let me explain what i am trying to do. I want the user to enter a city in the "Enter your city" input. And after that i want him to fill the "Enter your address" input field. So what i want to do is the autocomplete only to show the address from the chosen city. Not the duplicates from other cities. Only the address from the chosen city. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete